# How to sum functions in R?

Tags: r, function

I have a function which is intended to be a sum of functions, namely, I have `f(x) <- a * ecdf(x - 1) + b * ecdf(x - 2)`, where `a` and `b` are some real numbers. The problem is that, when trying to call this sum, R returns the following error: `non-numeric argument to binary operator`. So, how should functions be multiplied by the Euclidean parameter or summed in R? Why isn't there any mistake if I do the same thing to `dnorm()`, for example?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: `ecdf()` doesn't return values, it returns a function that itself would need to be evaluated at `x`.

Comment: ...I mean, I'm also assuming that when you write `f(x) <- ...` that that's not actually how you're trying to define a function, since in R the syntax would be `f <- function(x) {...}`.

Comment: @joran, does that mean that ecdfs cannot be summed and multiplied by a parameter? If not ecdfs, how can I sum other functions (for example, Kernel cdf estimators)?
And yes, for sure, this was not the way I was trying to define a function, just a math-style expression which I used here for convenience.

Comment: Of course they can, you just have to operate on the _calculated values_ of the functions, not the functions themselves. So if `foo` and `bar` are R functions, then you can certainly write `foo(x) + 2*bar(y)`, where `foo(x)` etc evaluate to (presumably) a vector of values.

Comment: Also it's a much better idea to write what you actually have instead of using expressions that aren't your actual code

Comment: I think you want something like `f <- function(x)  function(z) a * ecdf(x - 1)(z) + b * ecdf(x - 2)` which will return a new function `f`.

Comment: @MrFlick, yes, exactly. However, as I tried to write this kind of code, R returned `Error in ecdf(x - 1)(y) : attempt to apply non-function`, so I probably still do not do the right thing...

Comment: @Dason, sure, all the expressions I've used except f(x) are expressions from my actual code. I've used f(x) just because it is the desirable result and quite convenient notation, not a code.

Comment: Convenient notation doesn't beat out clearly showing what you actually coded. The code speaks more clearly than your convenient notation.